# dataframe column value combinations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have created dataframe like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b'],
                   'B': ['c','d'],
                    'C':[1,2]
                   })
df.head()

   A  B  C
0  a  c  1
1  b  d  2
```

i want to create combination of first two columns  `[ab,ad,cb,cd]` as a new dataframe header and values based on first df.

my expected new df is :

```
   ac ad bd ad
0  1   0  0  2
```

Comment: Is `bd` correct? Not `bc` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), add missing combinations by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), convert to one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose, last flatten `MultiIndex` by `map` with `join`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['A'], df['B']])
df1 = df.set_index(['A','B'])['C'].reindex(mux, fill_value=0).to_frame(0).T
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(''.join)
print (df1)
   ac  ad  bc  bd
0   1   0   0   2
```

Another solution is use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['A','B'])['C'].unstack(fill_value=0).stack().to_frame(0).T
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(''.join)
```